# c program looping with rows and columns

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that takes 3 inputs from the user: `row/columns count` and `number range start` and `number range end`.

In my case and for example lets say `4 1 16` so it means `4 rows and columns` print `numbers from` `1-16`.

I have a problem accomplishing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int num1,num2,count,i,y;
int main()
{
    count = 4;
    num1 = 1;
    num2 = 16;

for(i=1; i<=count; i++){


  for(y=num1; y<=num2; y++){
       printf("%d ",y);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Whereas I want my output to be:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Comment: Print and increment `num1` in the inner loop. Variable `num2` seems superfluous unless you use it to clamp the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(y=1; y<=count; y++){
     printf("%d ",num1++);
}
```

That way you will ensure that all the `numbers` will be printed. you can use `num1` variable that you have declared and initialized with `1`.

Don't use unnecessary global variables. And keep the declarations close to where you use them. That way you won't have to look in the top of the page to check the type or if you initialized or not.

```
for(i=1; i<=count; i++){
     printf("%d ",i);
     if( i % 4 == 0)
        printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print `4*(i-1)+y` instead of `y`:

```
printf("%d ",4*(i-1)+y);
```

Comment: @Stackingc What you had before made more sense, as you were looping through 4 rows and 4 columns.  My answer stands with the code as originally written.